# Ajax loader (.gif) file keeps on sniping at the start of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am just importing the below javascript file and css but when i run this page the ajax-loader just keeps on spinning.

Note: there is no body or content in the file at all other than what is mentioned below.

Any idea why the ajax-loader.gif spins ?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">

      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


   </head>

   <body>



   </body>

</html>
```

.However when i try the below links it works fine without the loader spinning.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You only need JQM.css, jquery.js and JQM.js in case you're not using a custom theme.

Comment: You included almost all files 2 times, a jquery.css is the same as jquery.min.css (only last is minified). So get rid of all the duplicate files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why two jquery mobiles just add one:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script> //<---either this
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>//<--or this
```

you have to pick only one of it, so update to this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

---

and you have loaded all the non-minified and minified css files too.